# Re-Magnetizing A Magna-Tip Screwdriver Handle

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic, magnet

***See what I added to the bottom of this question***

Sorry for the high school level question. I would rather not spend my time experimenting. I have a quality gunsmith screwdriver set. The set contains many tips, that are held into the screwdriver handle because the interior of the screwdriver was magnetized.  Stupid mistake on my part, I demagnetized the screwdriver.

I understand the methods of either running a magnet across the handle or coiling copper wire around the item and applying electricity. The problem is that the magnetizable portion of the handle is buried inside of the plastic handle. So the question really is:

**Can I wrap copper wire around the outside of the plastic handle (Which is a 1/2" away from the metal interior) apply current and have that work to re-magnetize the piece?**

The set is a couple of hundred dollars, and no individual replacement pieces are sold for the set....  Thanks!

Very small gun parts become magnetized relatively easily when working on firearms. Whether it is because they were kept when disassembled in a magnetic tray, or set close to a screwdriver or other object that was magnetized, becoming magnetized themselves.

In my case I have a large demagnetizer that I use for the purpose of not reinstalling parts that have become slightly magnetized. Unfortunately, the screwdriver was left too close to the demagnetizer when it was on................

The steel in the center of the screwdriver does not extend outside of the screwdriver handle. The only thing that does extend out is the potmetal extension that surrounds the bit when in place.

Therefore, the steel I need to re-magnetize is deep in the handle. Hence the reason for my question about electrical magnetizing through the plastic of the handle.

I will likely try finding a very small magnet & gluing it inside the exposed shaft to try and serve the same purpose.......

Comment: How deep where the tip goes? can you glue a small magnet down there?

Comment: That is a real possibility I might try.

Answer (score 1):

How did you demagnetize it? Did you drop it? How do you know there is an actual magnet in the handle and not just magnetized steel?

Because I don't think you can remagnetize an actual magnet like that. Iron or steel, yes.

In any case, sounds like no electronics lab which means you don't have the power supply for the massive current required, Better off buying some dangerously strong, large  1"x1" or 1" x 2" neodymium magnets and just rubbing that on your screwdriver shaft. I've accidentally magnetized lathe tools that way when it got stuck just once and I had to slide it off to remove it. They run about $50-$80USD on McMaster-Carr. They are strong enough that if you wave them in front of an aluminum plate you can noticeably feel the induced braking effect. I have huge power supplies and hollow coils that I wound specifically to try and reproduce the strength of the magnets and they still fall short by a lot.

I suppose you could make a tunnel with four such magnets and pass the screwdriver through, but that's a dangerous thing to build with so many strong magnets that you need to maneuver close together and fix.  And the magnets alone would cost more than a new set of screwdrivers.

You would need to fasten the magnets independently to aluminum brackets then fix those brackets to guides or grooves so you could bring them together to bolt the brackets down without risk of the magnets flipping around and slamming themselves together if you lose control. No free handling of the magnets into position if you like your fingers.

Comment: So the copper wrap is not possible because of the distance between the plastic and the metal interior?

Comment: @B.Varner Even if the handle was not there so you could get right up against the metal you don't have the equipment to produce a high enough current for a magnetic field strong enough. Even with that you'd need thousands of turns and the heat generated would also probably damage the handle. And that's if it's just steel and not a regular magnetic, because I'm pretty sure you can't re-magnetize what I assume is a rare earth magnet that way.

Comment: His demagnetizer doesn't supply enough power to do the opposite?

Comment: @gbarry He never said how it was demagnetized, that's why I asked if he dropped it and how he knew it was a magnet and not just steel. The update that it was a large demagnetizer that did it is a recent update. It's also easier to demagnetize than it is to magnetize since the magnetic domains repelling each other are always causing a magnet to want to demagnetize itself.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I resolved the problem.  The first response worked best for me.  I purchased a correct diameter round magnet & glued it into the bit holder/screwdriver.  Holds the bit fine.  Resolves the problem.